# Getting exception after undeploy & deploy the application in weblogic server

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

1. Started Weblogic server.
2. Deployed application into server.
3. Accessed the application for some time.
4. Undeployed the application from server.
5. Again deployed the same application into server

After 5th step getting the below exception and results blank page when try to access the application (It is working fine once I restart the server).

Is there any solution for this ?

Thanks,
Gopal.

```
Caused by: oracle.jbo.ConfigException: JBO-33001: STRINGMANAGER: Message file: 'oracle.jbo.common.CommonMessageBundle' not found. (Looking for '33001')
at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.loadFromClassPath(Configuration.java:457)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.PoolMgr.loadConfiguration(PoolMgr.java:756)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.PoolMgr.findPool(PoolMgr.java:591)
at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1508)
at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1485)
at oracle.cloud.applications.common.util.AMUtil.getAM(AMUtil.java:76)
at oracle.cloud.applications.common.util.AMUtil.getMyAM(AMUtil.java:98)
at oracle.cloud.applications.common.util.Configuration.getConfig(Configuration.java:242)
at oracle.cloud.applications.myapp.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:47)
at oracle.cloud.applications.common.util.Configuration.getFrequency(Configuration.java:150)
Caused by: oracle.mds.exception.MDSRuntimeException: MDS-00168: MDS object oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance@2391563b is being used after it or its MDSInstance or PManager has been released.
at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.checkNotReleased(MDSInstance.java:1600)
at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.getPersistenceManager(MDSInstance.java:906)
at oracle.mds.core.MDSSession.getPersistenceManager(MDSSession.java:2792)
at oracle.mds.core.MDSSession.getBaseMO(MDSSession.java:3874)
at oracle.mds.core.MDSSession.getMetadataObject(MDSSession.java:1750)
at oracle.adf.share.jndi.MDSBackingStore.documentExists(MDSBackingStore.java:159)
at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.loadFromClassPath(Configuration.java:443)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.PoolMgr.loadConfiguration(PoolMgr.java:756)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.PoolMgr.findPool(PoolMgr.java:591)
at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1508)
at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1485)
at oracle.cloud.applications.common.util.AMUtil.getAM(AMUtil.java:76)
at oracle.cloud.applications.common.util.AMUtil.getMyAM(AMUtil.java:98)
at oracle.cloud.applications.common.util.Configuration.getConfig(Configuration.java:242)
at oracle.cloud.applications.myapp.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:47)
at oracle.cloud.applications.common.util.Configuration.getFrequency(Configuration.java:150)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below link for answer.

[MDS-00168: MDS object is used after PManager has been relesed](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/990059)